Graph API via Powershell
I'm trying to get the Graph API to work via a REST call through Powershell, and I'm running into some issues.
Basically, I'm trying to create a new Entra role, by using Invoke-RestMethod towards the Graph API.
I've crafted my token, which works and I've implemented in other scripts
    $ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 
 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
$TokenAccess = $Tokenresponse.access_token

However, when I run the following code
$CreateRoleUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions"
$CreateRole = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CreateRoleUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($TokenAccess)" } -Method Post -Body $($CreateRoleDefinition | convertto-json) -ContentType "application/json"

I get an error
Invoke-RestMethod: { "error": {"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": "An unexpected \u0027PrimitiveValue\u0027 node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A \u0027StartArray\u0027 node was expected.",
"innerError": {
  "date": "2024-04-21T10:21:28",
  "request-id": "a274512b-c4b2-423d-ac2d-e81f4816b067",
  "client-request-id": "a274512b-c4b2-423d-ac2d-e81f4816b067"
}

I believe the JSON formatting in my query is correct, it was converted from a PSCustomObject and compared with this site for syntax.

Unicode character 027 is an apostrophe which has to be escaped.

That's strange, since there isn't an apostrophe anywhere in the code.

I figured it out. When converting to JSON, I had to specify the depth with the "-Depth" parameter, otherwise the default depth of 2 was used and the resulting JSON wasn't complete.
